# Zabbix 3.4: Is it possible for the agent to accumulate data if the connection with the APP is lost?

Tags: zabbix

I have installed Zabbix 3.4 by Oracle Linux 7.4

Is it possible for the agent to accumulate data if the connection with the APP is lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "APP" you mean Zabbix server, this is possible if you use active items. Agent will buffer values in the memory for a while and send them to the server when the connection is restored.

Comment: buffering possible only in memory?

Comment: For the agent, yes. If you want long-term buffering, consider Zabbix proxy.

Comment: agent and proxy must be together on server?

Comment: Proxy would be the one storing data on disk, so it must be somewhat close to the agent, but not necessarily on the same box. It is common to have one proxy for a remote environment like a branch office or a remote datacentre.